# JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile does not filter by extension

Tags: geotools

Running GeoTools 15.1 on Ubuntu

Using this code:

```
...
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;

public class GeoJson2Shape {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      File shpFile=null;

      System.out.println("Starting");

      File geojson = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile(".GeoJson", new  File("."), null);
...
```

I get this window:

[image]

No filtering but displaying all files. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the data type box from all to geojson and it will be filtered.

As to why it is not used when you open the chooser is a swing mystery that you will need to ask on stack overflow.

Comment: i'm calling a GeoTools method. therefor i'm asking here.

ok, interprete your answer as "yes, it's ok".

thanks

Comment: It is an issue I have seen in most swing programs